# Numpy, for all the negative elements, divided by the absolute value of the sum of all the negative values

Tags: python, numpy

```
data = np.array([-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3])
data[data < 0] = data[data < 0] / np.abs(np.sum(data[data < 0]))
data[data > 0] = data[data > 0] / np.abs(np.sum(data[data > 0]))

data
Out[109]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

When I run the code, it gives a zero-array. Why this happened? How should I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Your array is an integer type. Because of this, your code that performs division for the elements in your array will be done with integer arithmetic. The results of your array being all 0 are quite apparent, knowing that the array is an integer type. For the arithmetic operations in your code, you divide the affected elements in the array by a value greater than any of them. This causes the result to be fractional, or less than 1, which integer division will truncate to 0. To solve this, turn your array into floating point precision to preserve the fractional components of the resulting values:

```
data = np.array([-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=float)
data[data < 0] = data[data < 0] / np.abs(np.sum(data[data < 0]))
data[data > 0] = data[data > 0] / np.abs(np.sum(data[data > 0]))
```

Output:

```
>>> data
array([-0.5       , -0.33333333, -0.16666667,  0.        ,  0.16666667,
        0.33333333,  0.5       ])
```

Also, you can redefine the type after the array is defined. If changing the declaration of the array isn't an option, this is much more clear than relying on implicit type conversion, as per @Zein:

```
data = data.astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to convert the array `data` to float somehow. If you can, do it during definition as mentioned above by @rayryeng.
However, after definition you can just multiply it by `1.0` to make it `float` as follows,

```py
data = np.array([-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3])

data = data*1.0

data[data < 0] = data[data < 0] / np.abs(np.sum(data[data < 0]))
data[data > 0] = data[data > 0] / np.abs(np.sum(data[data > 0]))

data
```

Output:

```
array([-0.5       , -0.33333333, -0.16666667,  0.        ,  0.16666667,
        0.33333333,  0.5       ])
```

Comment: FYI, you can also redefine the type after the array is defined. This is much more clear than relying on implicit type conversion: `data = data.astype(float)`